# Combine background image with rgba but without gradient

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to combine a background image with a rgba color *without* using a rgba gradient?

Currently my css3 style looks like this:

```
html
{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)),
    url("../icons/sombrero.jpg")no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

But I imagine something like this:

```
html
{
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75),
    url("../icons/sombrero.jpg")no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

The rgba color should lay above the image.
I got the gradient-'hack' from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients). I search for an alternative to the gradient technique, no box-shadow trick.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ggwgz94s/ separately they work fine, together they don't work at all. i think it has to do with using an image: `background-image` and a color: `background` in the same context. `linear-gradient` works with background-image. But what's wrong with what you have now? I can't see anything wrong with it. The colors look great. :)

Comment: @yak613 it is because you can't place a background color over a background image. The reason the gradient worked is because it is rendered as a background image :D

Comment: Either use `box-shadow` or an pseudo element. Both are pretty simple.

Comment: there was an answer to that effect just a minute ago. got deleted...http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/ggwgz94s/ this was the code he tried.

Comment: It just annoys me that even in css3 you still need these 'hacks' to perform such simple tasks. It would be far more convenient and logic to use my 2nd example, wouldn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS color background over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632630/css-color-background-over-image)

Comment: @JacobGray No, the gradient technique isn't even named once there...

Comment: Could you not put the image on the `html` and the color on the `body`? - http://jsfiddle.net/rk1v1y1u/

Comment: @Paulie_D No, because the body cannot be width & height 100% in my case.

Comment: I only used the 100% as an indication. I'm curious to see what it is you are trying to do...do you have a design image we could see. That said, there is a solution you just don't like it. :)

Comment: Currently my project is private. I have also thought about this way to handle the problem, but now I decided to use a completely different technique (/ layout). Have a look at @vals answer. That is an answer I was hoping for. But thank you very much for your comment! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible probably in the future.

from the w3c draft:

> For example, one can use this as a simple way to "tint" a background
>   image, by overlaying a partially-transparent color over the top of the
>   other image:

```
background-image: image(rgba(0,0,255,.5)), url("bg-image.png");
```

> background-color does not work for this, as the
>   solid color it generates always lies beneath all the background
>   images.

[w3c documentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#color-images)

Comment: Thank you very much. That is some useful information!